# jQuery - iterate over event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a strange problem with a `.submit` handler.

```
function validateOnSubmit() {
    //sacar el rojo de textfield de producto
    if (currentRestrictions == null) {
        //debe seleccionar un producto
        $("#invalidProductDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    } else if (!currentRestrictions.allows($("#largo").val(), $("#ancho").val(), $("#calibre").val())) {
        //hay un error de validacion
        $("#invalidDimensionsDialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }
}
...
$("#aForm").submit(validateOnSubmit);
```

The problem with this (this?) code is that if it's cancelled (i.e. by reaching a `return false` statement) and the form is not submitted, the next time the form is told to be submitted, this handler will execute BUT even when not reaching the `return false` statements, it will not be submitted.

It never happened me before and **I don't expect you find a solution for this** (since a lot of code is involved). However, since I'm using a framework which puts some boilerplate I ask:

**Q**: Is there a way I can iterate (to debug) through the list of .submit handlers?

Comment: So your question isn't what's wrong with the code, but instead how to determine if it is the only submit event bound to the element, correct? You can check for other jQuery bound events, however you can't check for events bound by things other than jquery.

Comment: Yes, that's my Q. I think nobody can help me with this since it's a huge code I can't post here.

Comment: I have another suggestions to help you debug it, but it doesn't at all answer your question because it goes in a different route just to ensure that this particular function properly returns undefined when it's valid.

Comment: is it that you need explicitly to do an ajax call, or is the form action properly set ?

Comment: Basically, it's a function proxy that logs all important information about the function when it is executed. http://jsfiddle.net/jab78/ you can use this to confirm that it is in fact returning undefined. Otherwise, i would suggest using the Visual Event bookmarklet to inspect the bound events.

Comment: I used your function, and the logged return value was "false" when I make it fail, and "undefined" when I don't make it fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `submit` call is outside of your function...

Ok then...

Is it only that you need to do an ajax call to the server at the end of your submit function ?

Comment: i don't understand what difference that makes

Comment: that .submit call is to craete the handler, if I added inside the handler, then it'd never be called xD.

Comment: true... i didn't notice that it was the same fucntion you needed to call

Answer (score 0):

How to debug - It worked for me and fund the actual problem! - throug the list of event handlers (**warning**: tested in version >= 1.8; i **think** lower versions use a different method):

Say your object is: `$("aSelector")`.

You can get the handlers with `$._data($("aSelector")[0], "events")`, which returns a dictionary in the format: {handlerName: handlerList}, being `handlerList` a list of handler objects which have a `function` property having the actual handler.

Had an error in such additional handler (it doesn't matter at all at the effect of this question, since the question was, finally, about how to debug the handlers).

Answer (score -1):

**Q:** Is there a way I can iterate (to debug) through the list of .submit handlers?

**A:** You can use Firefox for this. In the firefox debugger tab, look at the events pane. There you'll find all events bound by code on your page.

**Source**:

1. Debugger [Events pane](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger#Events_pane)
2. Here's a link to to explain [how to use the firefox debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)...

Comment: Explain the relationship between listing the handlers & using the debugger, and I (at least) remove the downvote.

Comment: Undownvoted. This lets me iterate over the jQuery handlers? or shows native handlers? remember that the native handlers are not the handlers assigned with jQuery, but inner handlers which loop thru a kind of list or chain holding the actual handlers I need. Does that pane show me that handlers list? (e.g. all the jquery handlers assigned to the .submit event)